# problems in mathematics

Tags: soft-question

Where can i find long and interesting problems related to analysis (or to mathematics in general) in order to prepare for the Phd qualifying exams (outside of usa) 
i don't want research problems, but enough difficult for self training and that can be solved in some hours.

Comment: In my university, the final exam for M.Sc. in mathematics and to continue for PhD requires deep knowledge in *undergraduate* stuff, but basic and advanced.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late, but in case somebody else, like me, gets here looking for the same answer as you:

[Problems and Solutions in Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814304964) looks quite advanced and meets your topic requirements.
The [cambridge tripos archives](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/postgrad/mathiii/pastpapers/), should also meet your needs...
You Also have [Problems and Theorems in Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902244) I & II.

At Slightly lower level (regarding required knowledge, not difficulty), you have "Berkeley Problems in Mathematics". Also, as you speak French ["Agrégation Externe de Mathématiques"](http://agreg.org/sujets.html) could be a good warm-up.

I'll start training on those alongside my job, for the same reason as you.
Hope it'll help some people.

Answer (score 1):

Do you speak French?
[Polytechnique](http://www.sujets-de-concours.net/concours_filiere.php?concours=x&filiere=mp), [Centrale](https://www.concours-centrale-supelec.fr/CentraleSupelec)
(look for Mathematiques 1 & 2)

Comment: Yes, i speak french, but these "concours" are somewhat very basic, i need problems that involve advanced maths like measure theory, functional analysis, pde's, differential geometry, (algebraic) topology and harmonic analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Most universities have their PhD qualifying exams posted on their websites. For example:

University of Florida
http://gma.math.ufl.edu/past-exams/first-year-analysis/

UCLA
https://www.math.ucla.edu/grad/handbook/quals

Stanford
http://mathematics.stanford.edu/academics/graduate/phd-program/phd-qualifying-exams/

To name a few. I googled "phd qualifying exams math." It appears the page at the University of Florida also has qualifiers for Measure Theory, Complex Analysis, and Functional Analysis.

Comment: UIUC also has their old comp exams online: http://www.math.illinois.edu/GraduateProgram/Study/study.html

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo that's good to know. I like to collect these sorts of problems myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you seek, but do you know the [Berkeley problems in Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387204296)?

Comment: Actually, i am looking for problems involving deep and advanced math concepts (advanced undergrad. level)